# $y < 2x + 1$ From my understanding y is larger.

Tags: linear-algebra

When x equal 2, y equal 5, and so forth. I don't understand this. Please help. The question is, how is y less than

$$y = 2( 2 ) + 1$$
$$y = 5$$

Comment: When $x=2$, $y<5$ not $y=5$. I'm having a hard time understanding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inequality. What this is a statement about the values of numbers $x$ and $y$. We do not know any relationship between $x$ and $y$ other than this one. So if $x=2$, we have no idea what $y$ equals, only that $y<2x+1=5$, so $y$ is less than $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the inequality $y>x$, Solving this with the original inequality gives $x>-1$

So your observation that $y>x$ can be concluded if $x>-1$